# Unsafe use of expression of type 'any' for return statements in Typescript function

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, backend, nestjs

```
async fetchDetail(token: string): Promise < object > {

  const headersRequest = {
    Authorization: `Basic ${token}`,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  }

  return await this.httpService.get( < URL > , {
      headers: headersRequest
    })
    .toPromise()
    .then((response): object => response.data)
    .catch(() => {
      throw new NotFoundException()
    })
}
```

I keep getting a lint issue for this line **.then((response): object => response.data)**

which states
**Unsafe use of expression of type 'any'**

Comment: ERROR: /Users/ghostChat/microserviceDetails/src/modules/detailFinder/detailFinder.service.ts:16:35 - Unsafe use of expression of type 'any'.

This is the entire error statement. The error is flagged for "response.data"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that it's because `response` is a "generic object" and typescript can't "identify" that it has a `.data` attribute.

In order to fix that we can declare an interface of a type:

```
type hasData = { data: any };
```

and then use it to "explain" to TS that we expect the response to contain that attribute:

```
.then((response: hasData): object => response.data)
```

Comment: Had to change it to 
type hasData = { data: object };